# WPF :: Custom Control's Dependency Properties Aren't Working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

I'm making a `Ribbon` control for a WYSIWYG HTML editor. The ribbon has the typical Bold, Italic, Underline, FontFamily, etc. controls that you'd expect to see. I'll focus on the **Bold** functionality for this example.

I want the `Ribbon` to be reuseable, so I've added a Dependency Property (DP) and associated property wrapper to the control's code behind (standard boilerplate stuff):

```
public partial class EditorRibbon: UserControl
{
  public static readonly DependencyProperty IsBoldProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register(
     "IsBold", 
     typeof (bool), 
     typeof (EditorRibbon), 
     new PropertyMetadata(default(bool)));

  public bool IsBold
  {
     get { return (bool) GetValue(IsBoldProperty); }
     set { SetValue(IsBoldProperty, value); }
  }
}
```

... and in the XAML I have my `RibbonToggleButton`, and I've bound the `IsChecked` property to the dependency property:

```
<UserControl x:Class="My.EditorRibbon">
  <r:RibbonToggleButton Command="ToggleBold"
                        ToolTip="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Command.Text}"
                        SmallImageSource="{StaticResource ToggleBoldIcon}" 
                        IsChecked="{Binding IsBold}" />

</UserControl>
```

In my `Editor` window, I've bound the `IsBold` property of the `EditorRibbon` to a conventional property on the window's ViewModel:

```
<Window x:class="My.MainWindow>
  <My.EditorRibbon IsBold="{Binding SelectionIsBold}"/>
</Window>
```

Here is the `SelectionIsBold` property:

```
public bool SelectionIsBold
{
  get { return _selection.IsBold(); }
}
```

... and I raise the `NotifyPropertyChanged()` event (in the MainWindow's ViewModel) whenever the selection in the `RichTextBox` changes:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : BaseViewModel 
{
    public MainWindowViewModel(MainWindow window)
    {
       rtb.SelectionChanged += rtb_OnSelectionChanged;
    }

    private void rtb_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
    {
      NotifyPropertyChanged(()=>SelectionIsBold);
    }

}
```

To my mind, this should be enough to change the `IsChecked` state of the `RibbonToggleButton` whenever the selection changes... but it doesn't.  Despite changing the selection, and despite the `NotifyPropertyChanged()` firing as expected, a breakpoint on the `SelectionIsBold` property (*yes, I've deselected VS's "Step Over Property" setting*) is never hit.  Somewhere, the request to refresh the value isn't propagating correctly.

Do I need to trigger NotifyPropertyChanged() on the IsBold property after the value is set in the setter?

Comment: Don't you have to Bind your command? Command="{Binding ToggleBold}"

Comment: where is 'rtb_OnSelectionChanged'

Comment: @Neil - rtb_OnSelectionChanged is in the Window that contains both the RichTextBox and the EditorRibbon.

Comment: @ScottNimrod - No.  The command is functioning perfectly as is.

Comment: Do you need to specify UpdateSourceTrigger or specify Mode as TwoWay?

Comment: Are you seeing any binding errors in your output window while starting the debug session?

Answer (score 0):

Change the IsBold binding to  the following

```
<UserControl x:Class="My.EditorRibbon" x:Name="EditorRibbonInstance">
<r:RibbonToggleButton Command="ToggleBold"
                    ToolTip="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Command.Text}"
                    SmallImageSource="{StaticResource ToggleBoldIcon}" 
                    IsChecked="{Binding IsBold, ElementName=EditorRibbonInstance, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</UserControl>
```

With that you are sure that the binding is going to the property of the control and not to the datacontext of the control

Comment: I tried it, no joy - something still isn't working.  The IsChecked property still isn't updating when selection changes.

Comment: I forgot add mode TwoWay, try with that

Comment: Why would it be TwoWay?  The IsChecked property isn't pushing its value anywhere - it's strictly being read from the selection.  Either way, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to fire notifypropertychanged in ViewModel. Try somethings like this in ViewModel:

```
 protected void FirePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }


->>   FirePropertyChanged("SelectionIsBold")
```

The reason is: now, your data context is ViewModel, all of binding to ViewModel must be triggered by ViewModel's properties

Comment: I moved my subscription to the event and the event handler to the ViewModel and still no joy.  I'm updating my post to reflect this.

Comment: My NotifyPropertyChanged(()=> SelectionIsBold) method does this very thing, it just uses reflection instead of a string to get the property name.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, I never saw the injection of the Window to the ViewModel before... are you using some Kind of DI for the injection?

I think it is not a good idea to use the selection changed Event on viewmodel... This is not mvvm from my Point of view...

Are you updating the _selection somewhere? Might be that you always checking the same selection?!

Answer (score -1):

You are not properly binding the command property of your button.

Should reflect something like this:

```
Command="{Binding ToggleBold}"
```

Comment: I respectfully disagree.  The ToggleBold command is working perfectly.  The button disables when CanExecute() fails, and the Execute() method toggles bold exactly as advertised.  The only part that isn't working is wiring up IsChecked to reflect the current selection.

Comment: Okay. I didn't know you could assign a string value to a command property without the Binding syntax ceremony.

Comment: Just so you know, it was not I that downvoted you.  :-)